# Google Spreadsheets showing "shared with xxx" count greater than actual?

Tags: google-sheets, importrange

For every one of my Google Spreadsheets, the sharing settings is on "Specific people can access" and each sheet is shared with three people I know. Their names are listed when I click on the blue "Share" button.

But if I hover over the blue "Share" button, it says "Shared with xxx people" and that xxx is always greater than 3, looks like between 10 and 90.

What is up with that - is everybody experiencing the same thing?

---

Edit: It seems like every time you use the `IMPORTRANGE` function and link data from that sheet the "shared" number goes up. If that is the case, it’s a very different definition of "shared" than what is usually thought of.

Comment: @pnuts. I think it is the answer, but not sure. I didn't want to presume anything.

Comment: No repro here. Do you still see this?

Comment: looks like google fixed this... i only see 6 people now in that sheet

Comment: Since this is a web application this could be the UI displaying incorrect info. I recommend completely clearing the cache & cookies on your browser, making sure the browser is up to date, and seeing if the same info is displayed in other browsers (Safari, Chrome, IE, Firefox). If you are using Chrome, I also recommend testing in an incognito window as this disables extensions & apps as possible causes. Add your results as an edit to your question. Thanks! Oh, thought of 1 more thing: Does anyone else that has the same file shared with them also see the same number of "shared with" people?

Answer (score 1):

No - I just checked a couple of mine, and the count is ok.  Both ones that are shared with specfic people (one with 1, one with 3)

Comment: so what could be the explanation of why I have more than the number of people shared?

Comment: A bug which was introduced by Google and then removed quickly?    Is it still happening for you ?  Is there anything special about the three people you've shared with?

Comment: It's still like that for me. Nothing has changed. Nothing special about these people that share the spreadsheet with me.

Comment: fyi, the sheets I tested it on would not have used the IMPORTRANGE function - this would be consistent with me not reproducing the issue.    (As you say, it's an unusual definition of "shared" - it's more a count of uses of the data, rather than shares of the file.)